# This app could not be installed at this time. Found WatchKit 2.0 app named Astronaut.app when we already found AstroJump WatchKit App.app

Tags: watchkit, watchos

I am trying to build watchOS SpriteKit app, but when i try to run it it still throws me this kind of error:
This app could not be installed at this time.
Found WatchKit 2.0 app named Astronaut.app when we already found AstroJump WatchKit App.app

Could you please help me solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Build and Clean helped...